# R create sf polyline from nested list of coordinates

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a nested list of coordinates in the following format:

```
feature <- list(type = "Feature", properties = list(`_leaflet_id` = 125L, 
    feature_type = "polyline"), geometry = list(type = "LineString", 
    coordinates = list(list(-176.264648, 59.355596), list(-165.541992, 
        60.951777), list(-158.510742, 57.891497))))
```

I am trying to convert this to a simple feature sf layer by unpacking the the nested list coordinates into a geometry.

I've tried the following experiments, trying to just make a dataframe of coords first, but none seem to work.

```
xs <- as.data.frame(feature) 
xs <- bind_rows(feature[["geometry"]][["coordinates"]])
xs <- feature[["geometry"]] %>% set_names() %>% bind_rows()
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Note:  the number of coordinate pairs (vertices on the line) is arbitrary may change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `feature` looks like the result of converting `geojson` into an R object

If you have access to the geojson object *before* it is converted into your `feature`, then you can ignore the `to_json()` step(s) here

```r
library(sf)

## convert back to JSON

### Option 1
js <- jsonify::to_json(feature, unbox = TRUE)

### Option 2
js <- jsonlite::toJSON(feature, auto_unbox = TRUE)

## Then you can convert to SF

### Option 1
geojsonsf::geojson_sf(js)

### Option 2
sf::st_read(js)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you unlist it, and put it into a matrix, the st_linestring from the sf package can then use it.

```
coords <- matrix(unlist(feature$geometry$coordinates), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2)

linestring <- st_linestring(coords)

plot(linestring)
```

Comment: Thanks Jahi, this makes sense but the other response marked as answer converts to sf as the question asked.  But my guess taking the linestring to sf would also be easy

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
  
map_dfr(feature$geometry$coordinates,
        ~ data.frame(.x) %>% set_names(c("x", "y"))) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  st_linestring() %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 4326) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(lwd = 3, lineend = "round")
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: THanks Andrew, this makes sense but the other response marked as answer converts to sf as the question asked.  But my guess taking the linestring to sf would also be easy

Comment: @DarwinsBeard I updated it so that it is a simple sf feature. But I still think SymbolixAU provides the best / most straightforward.